# The correct way of showing data as HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've used ASP.NET MVC5 in my project.
I want to show data that recorded in database as a part of HTML page.
As a simplest data in database that recorded, I have `<div>This is a div.</div>`

And in cshtml file I have

```
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Description)
</div>
```

But data does not show as a HTML tag.

How can I explain to the browser that my data must be interpreted as an HTML tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw` instead of `@Html.DisplayFor`.

Most of the HTML helper functions in Razor automatically encode the values to help prevent cross-site scripting attacks. If you're going to render raw HTML into the user's browser I hope you've sanitized it to prevent attacks.